# asp.net mvc - Error when added new model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

Im new to asp.net mvc. I'm trying add new model class but it got error. After some research i put **`Database.SetInitializer<STF_SEAL_MANAGEMENT_TEST>( null );`** in Application_start in Gobal.asax.cs but i got another error saying `"The type or namespace name 'STF_SEAL_MANAGEMENT_TEST1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"` Please help.

Comment: [How to ask a question the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: @Iridio Appreciate if you could help me on those as well.

Comment: It sounds like you may have more than one connection string. You are initializing "STF_SEAL_MANAGEMENT_TEST" and getting an error for "STF_SEAL_MANAGEMENT_TEST1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the whole DB, and rerun the application again. Its works fine.